# How can I use edgeOptions args in the webdriverIO (or protractor)conf file to load extension? for new edge drivers (81.xx)

Tags: protractor, webdriver, microsoft-edge, webdriver-io

I'm trying to automate an extension for Microsoft Edge (Chromium) and it was working fine until the Microsoft Edge browser got updated to 80.xx and ended the support of chromeOptions for their new edge drivers.

Like earlier, I was using chromeOptions with Edge driver to load the extension but now by ending the support of chromeOption for the new edge drivers, I'm not able to load the extension or pass any arguments to the Edge Browser for WebdriverIO ( or Protractor) framework.

So how can I use the edgeOptions in the conf file to pass the arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway, I got the solution for this, just need to add "ms:edgeOptions" under capabilities (like goog:chromeOptions) and by doing that it will treat the args as Chromium.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.